# Pytorch: RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0 using 2D CNN model with pretrained vgg_16

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am working on cardiac CT data(axial, sagittal, coronal). I am using
the pre-trained model vgg_16. But got the following error. According
to this error, my dimension is not correct but according to my code,
I write things coreectly Can somebody guide me regarding this I try
to correct my code already but got the same error? Below is Error and
Code.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "ct_pretrained.py", line 199, in <module>
>    loss, metric = train(model, train_loader, optimizer)
>    File "ct_pretrained.py", line 57, in train
>    output = model(axial, sagittal, coronal, emr)
> File "/root/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site->packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
>    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
>    File "/data/heart_ct/torch/models/test.py", line 38, in forward
>    axial_feature = self.axial_model(axial)
> File "/root/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site->packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
>    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
> File "/root/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site->packages/torchvision/models/vgg.py", line 46, in forward
>    x = self.classifier(x)
> File "/root/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site->packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
>    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
> File "/root/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site->packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 93, in forward
>    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
> File "/root/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-> packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1690, in linear
>    ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
>    RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0
> ```

The code is:

```
 import torch
        import torch.nn as nn
        from torchvision import models
        
        __all__ = ['VGG']
        
        class VGG(nn.Module):
        
            def __init__(self, is_emr=False, mode='sum'):
                super().__init__()
                self.is_emr = is_emr
                self.mode = mode
                in_dim = 45
        
                self.axial_model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
                out_channels = self.axial_model.features[0].out_channels
                self.axial_model.features[0] = nn.Conv2d(1, out_channels, kernel_size=7, stride=1, padding=0, bias=False)
                self.axial_model.features[3] = nn.MaxPool2d(1)
                num_ftrs = self.axial_model.classifier.in_features #error in this line of code
                self.axial_model.classifier = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 15)
        
        
        
                self.sa_co_model = models.vgg16(pretrained=True)
                self.sa_co_model.features[0] = nn.Conv2d(1, out_channels, kernel_size=7, stride=1, padding=(3,0), bias=False)
                self.sa_co_model.features[3] = nn.MaxPool2d(1)
                self.sa_co_model.classifier = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 15)
        
                if self.is_emr:
                    self.emr_model = EMRModel()
                    if self.mode == 'concat': in_dim = 90
        
                self.classifier = Classifier(in_dim)
        
            def forward(self, axial, sagittal, coronal, emr):
                axial = axial[:,:,:-3,:-3]
                sagittal = sagittal[:,:,:,:-3]
                coronal = coronal[:,:,:,:-3]
        
                axial_feature = self.axial_model(axial)
                sagittal_feature = self.sa_co_model(sagittal)
                coronal_feature = self.sa_co_model(coronal)
                out = torch.cat([axial_feature, sagittal_feature, coronal_feature], dim=1)
        
                if self.is_emr:
                    emr_feature = self.emr_model(emr)
                    if self.mode == 'concat':
                        out = torch.cat([out, emr_feature], dim=1)
                    elif self.mode == 'sum':
                        out += emr_feature
        
                out = self.classifier(out)
        
                return out
```

Comment: (1) please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your question properly. (2)  please do **not** post screen shots: copy/paste the logs/error messages.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests: there's a mismatch between the dimension of the computed features `out` of your backbones and the dimensions of the classification layer of `self.classifier`.
Try to inspect (in debug mode, or using `print`) the shape and dimensions of `out` and what is `in_dim` of the classifier layer.